# Wsdl client works in windows but not in linux environment

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I'm a project than I generate a wsdl client with apache cfx.
When I run my project in mi local machine with Windows it works perfectlly, but when I was to try in machine with SO Linux (Red hat) it didn't work.
My xml since Windows is:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken-3e963a94-b8fc-4876-ace8-b675f270d3a0'>
                <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>mypass</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <ns4:HeaderReq xmlns:ns4='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/general/Headers' xmlns:ns3='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/common/ExcepcionGeneral' xmlns:ns2='http://www.something.com/ws/iss/nameWebConsume' locale='es_MX' codIdioma='UTF-8'>
            <Deploy>
                ***
            </Deploy>
            <Access>
                ***
            </Access>
            <Consumer>
                ***
            </Consumer>
            <RequestData>
                ***
            </RequestData>
        </ns4:HeaderReq>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <CheckSomething xmlns='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/nameWebConsume' xmlns:ns4='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/general/Headers' xmlns:ns3='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/common/ExcepcionGeneral' xmlns:ns2='http://www.something.com/ws/iss/nameWebConsume'>
            <Folio>123456789</Folio>
        </CheckSomething>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

My xml since linux is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soap:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken-9d835b01-63d0-4d88-9d15-6c06b73531a2'>
                <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>mypass</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <ns2:HeaderReq xmlns:ns2='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/general/Headers' xmlns:ns3='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/common/ExcepcionGeneral' xmlns:ns4='http://www.something.com/ws/iss/nameWebConsume' codIdioma='UTF-8' locale='es_MX'>
            <Deploy>
                ***
            </Deploy>
            <Access>
                ***
            </Access>
            <Consumer>
                ***
            </Consumer>
            <RequestData>
                ***
            </RequestData>
        </ns2:HeaderReq>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns4:CheckSomething xmlns:ns2='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/general/Headers' xmlns:ns3='http://www.something.com/ws/nss/common/ExcepcionGeneral' xmlns:ns4='http://www.something.com/ws/iss/nameWebConsume'>
            <Folio>123456789</Folio>
        </ns4:CheckSomething>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As you can see there are different tags from both SO, my question is: How I can create the same xml request to consume wsdl service?

My code configuration in classes, every header looks like I post

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "HeaderRequestType", propOrder = {
    "deploy",
    "access",
    "consumer",
    "requestData"
})
public class HeaderRequestType {...}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CheckSomething", namespace = "http://www.something.com/ws/iss/nameWebConsume", propOrder = {
    "folio"
})
public class CheckSomething {...}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Deploy", propOrder = {
    ...
})
public class Deploy {...}
```

My interface where I consume SOAP

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.something.com/ws/iss/nameWebConsume", name = "nameWebConsume")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface CheckSomething {

    @WebMethod
    public void CheckSomething(
        @WebParam(partName = "request", name = "CheckSomethingIn", targetNamespace = "http://www.something.com/ws/iss/nameWebConsume") CheckSomethingInType request,
        @WebParam(partName = "headerRequest", name = "HeaderReq", targetNamespace = "http://www.something.com/ws/nss/general/Headers", header = true) HeaderRequestType headerRequest,
        @WebParam(partName = "response", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT, name = "CheckSomethingOut", targetNamespace = "http://www.something.com/ws/iss/nameWebConsume") javax.xml.ws.Holder<CheckSomethingOutType> response,
        @WebParam(partName = "headerResponse", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT, name = "HeaderRes", targetNamespace = "http://www.something.com/ws/nss/general/Headers", header = true) javax.xml.ws.Holder<HeaderResponseType> headerResponse
    ) throws CheckSomethingFault;
    
}
```

That's it.
I you need more files where I have configuration I will update my post.
Update 1
I have a response in windows good (with data) and when I try in linux I have an error says: Error in data integration cvc-complex-type 2.4: in element

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "doesn't work". What does your application do when run on Linux? Is it returning the wrong output? If so, please include details of what it should return and what it actually does. Is it reporting an error? If so, please edit your question to include the full details of the error. If it is something else, please explain clearly why you consider that it isn't working.

Comment: _It works on my machine_ - _Then we'll ship your machine_ - And that's how Docker was born.